# Erro de variável não declarada

Tags: php, funções

Estou com problema de declação de variável na minha função PHP.

**Mensagem de erro:**

> Notice: Undefined variable: extra in caminho\do\arquivo\functions.php on line 58

**A função:**

```
function show_users($user_id=0){

if ($user_id > 0){
    $follow = array();
    $fsql = "SELECT user_id FROM following WHERE follower_id='$user_id'";
    $fresult = mysql_query($fsql);

    while($f = mysql_fetch_object($fresult)){
        //array_push($follow, $f->user_id);
        $follow[] = $f->user_id;
    }
    if (count($follow)){
        $id_string = implode(',', $follow);
        $extra =  " AND id IN ($id_string)";
    }else{
        return array();
    }
}
$users = array();
$sql = "SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE status='active' $extra ORDER BY username";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($data = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
    $users[$data->id] = $data->username;
}
return $users;}
```

A Linha em questão é:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE status='active' $extra ORDER BY username";
```

Como resolver?

Comment: remove $extra... ou declare ela com algum valor....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema parece-me ser que a variável não fica declarada nos casos em que a condição de um dos `if`é falsa. Tanto deste `if (count($follow)){` como deste `if ($user_id > 0){`, a falhar um a variável nunca é declarada.

Assim para resolver isso pode declarar-se a variável, vazia, como precaução.
No caso de o código entrar no if e receber novo valor tudo bem. Mas no caso de não entrar no if, então já não estraga a query.

Assim teste:

```
$extra = ''; // <= acrescento ao código
if ($user_id > 0){
    $follow = array();
```

Comment: Qual modo mais eficiente? Isso se puder...

Comment: @MarcelloInfoweb, penso que aqui não faz muita diferença em termos de eficiência. Se quiser pode tambem colocar no `else` do `if ($user_id > 0){`